# Cropping image in a given square size in Android?

Tags: android, image, crop

I am using this library [simplecropimage](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage/tree/master/simple-crop-image-lib/src/eu/janmuller/android/simplecropimage) this works fine but I want the cropping area in a square(in this it can be resizable and rectangular) and the square can be move. I want to crop the image in a square keeping the same aspect ratio.

Comment: @HareshChhelana i have used that library that is full of bugs.... dnt knw why they are not trying to update that library

Comment: Try out this : https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

Comment: yes that library works i know thanks...

Comment: @HareshChhelana and Moubeen i do not have any issue. would you listify some issue. so that i can make changes before my app comes to market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your crop class using intent

just use this

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_CLASS.this, CropImage.class);

    // tell CropImage activity to look for image to crop

    intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, filePath);

    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

    // use same aspect ratio for square size crop
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 1);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 1);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

HOPE IT HELPS..!

Comment: Its working but what if i put large value than 1. on X,and Y.

Comment: it is aspect ratio.....if you use 1 for both then it will show square size for crop,if you use 2:3(ASPECT_X=2,ASPECT_X=3) then it will show a rectangular shape for crop.......use aspect ratio according to your need..